# Selecting largest money value in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have this string:

" da licitação: r$ **43.470,00** (quarenta e três mil, quatrocentos e setenta reais)\n\n3 dos recursos orçamento são r$ **24.123,88**"

Note that there could be several money values in my strings. 
I want to separate only the largest, return should be "43.470,00" or 43,470.00 or 43470.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Create regular expression pattern for currencies
currency_pattern = re.compile(r"r\$ ([1-9][0-9.]*(?:,[0-9][0-9.]*)?)")

# Find the currencies in the string
currencies = currency_pattern.findall(" da licitação: r$ 43.470,00 (quarenta e três mil, quatrocentos e setenta reais)\n\n3 dos recursos orçamento são r$ 24.123,88")

# Reformat strings and cast to float
normalized_currencies = (float(currency.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.')) for currency in currencies)

# Now we can easily find the maximum value using the `max` function
max_currency = max(normalized_currencies)
print(max_currency)
```

> 43470.0

Comment: It does work for the given example, however, using a very similar string from a list results in 43.47. For some reason it is killing the zeroes. If I print that string: "da licitação: r$ 43.470,00 (quarenta e três mil, quatrocentos e setenta reais)

3 dos recursos orça". Any idea?

Comment: I've updated the code a bit. Can you give it another try? :) If it still doesn't work, can you please give me the faulty string?

Comment: Worked now, tks!

Comment: there could be some cases where there are extra spaces between the currency string or even no space (eg.: "r$  43.470,00", "r$ 43 .470,00", "r$ 43.4 70,00", "r$43.470,00", "r$43. 470,00"). Would you have a suggestion to treat that in the currency pattern?

Comment: Sure. Try changing the pattern to: `r\$ ?([1-9][0-9. ]*(?:,[0-9 ][0-9. ]*)?)`, and add `.replace(' ', '')`

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex for this task:

```
import re

s = ''' da licitação: r$ 43.470,00 (quarenta e três mil, quatrocentos e setenta reais)\n\n3 dos recursos orçamento são r$ 24.123,88'''
m = max(re.findall(r'\d+\.?\d*,?\d*', s), key=lambda v: float(v.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.')), default=None)
print(m)
```

Prints:

```
43.470,00
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it (returns an integer!):
I took important part of the code from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-all-the-numbers-in-a-string-using-regular-expression-in-python/)

```
# Python3 program to extract all the numbers from a string 
import re 

# Function to extract all the numbers from the given string 
def getNumbers(str): 
    array = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', str) 
    return array 

# Driver code 
string = "adbv34.5hj43hvb42"
line = ''
line = re.sub('[!@#$]', '', string)

array = getNumbers(line)

arra_num = []

for nums in array:
    arra_num.append(int(nums))

print(max(arra_num))
```